# JSP and AJAX for stock quotation

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp

As an exercise, I'm trying to create a simple page where you have two stock quotation, set to starting values `100` and `200`. The methods `updateValues()` modify the quotation value by +/- 1% and the `displayAction()` method return the String "<name of the quotation> = <value of the quotation>". Anyway, if I click the button "Refresh Values" the two quotation doesn't change. Wat I'm doing wrong?

Here's my index.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<jsp:useBean id="enel" class="it.unitn.studenti.porcelli.leonardo.esamefebbraio2022.businessobject.Enel" scope="application"></jsp:useBean>
<jsp:useBean id="webuild" class="it.unitn.studenti.porcelli.leonardo.esamefebbraio2022.businessobject.WeBuild" scope="application"></jsp:useBean>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PWEB Banking</title>

</head>
<body>
<script>
    function startIsClicked(){
        document.querySelector("#start_button").disabled = true;
        document.querySelector("#stop_button").disabled = false;
    }
    function stopIsClicked(){
        document.querySelector("#start_button").disabled = false;
        document.querySelector("#stop_button").disabled = true;
    }
    function refreshValues(enel, webuild){
        const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onload = function (){
            const newEnelValue = <%enel.updateValue();%>;
            document.getElementById("Enel").innerHTML = enel.displayAction();
            const newWebuildValue = <%webuild.updateValue();%>;
            document.getElementById("Webuild").innerHTML = webuild.displayAction();
        }
        xhttp.open("GET", "index.jsp", true);
        xhttp.send();
    }

</script>
<div id="buttons">
    <button id="start_button" type="button" name="start" onclick="startIsClicked()">Start</button>
    <button id="stop_button" type="button" name="start" onclick="stopIsClicked()" disabled>Stop</button>
</div>
<div id="Enel">
    <%=enel.displayAction()%>
</div>
<div id="Webuild">
    <%=webuild.displayAction()%>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="refreshValues(<%=enel%>, <%=webuild%>)">Refresh Values</button>
<br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ... any output from the browser console when you click that? I'd start with that.

Comment: Look at the generated source. I think there’s some confusion about when and/or where code is being executed. If you want to get a value through XHR (unrelated, but consider using `fetch` etc) just get the value, then *use* that value.

Comment: ... I also don't see where "displayAction()" is defined, unless I missed something. Or is that defined in 'enel' and 'webuild' beans? Are those beans somehow returning javascript objects? Seeing generated code would help here.

Comment: I've seen that generated code doesn't recognize the jsp scriplets in javascript code. For example const newEnelValue = <%enel.updateValue();%>; is seen as const newEnelValue = ;